# add a Element in a list

Tags: c

I want to know what is the reason of segmentation fault 11.
I have written the code to add a new element to a list. But it can never succeed run and I also have no idea how to alter my code.

```
typedef struct ll{
    int val;
    struct ll *next;
}ll_t;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    //int i;
    //int shmid;
    ll_t *list=NULL;
    //int *array=NULL;

    list=malloc(sizeof(ll_t));
    list->val=1;
    list->next=NULL;

    list->next->val=2;
    list->next->next=NULL;

    while(list->next!=NULL){
        printf("the number is: %d", list->val);
        list=list->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You never initialize next so it will cause seg fault

Comment: Learn to walk through your code with a debugger. As Fredrik points out, you never set a struct at list->next, so when you access it (list->next->val), your app crashes. This will show up immediately in the debugger.

Comment: Thank you! I have already got the points of it and also corrected!

Comment: Your code has memory issues, a live test of it https://segfault.stensal.com/a/2rpFTflGKb8dnQ2X,  you can try to fix it and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation faults occur when you try to access memory that doesn't belong to you.

To quote the authors of the book Three Easy Pieces (It's a book on operating systems. Great read btw), a segmentation fault is just a fancy word for:

> **YOU DID SOMETHING WRONG WITH
>   MEMORY YOU FOOLISH PROGRAMMER AND I AM ANGRY.**

```
list=malloc(sizeof(ll_t));
list->val=1;
list->next=NULL;    <----- This is where the problem starts.
```

You assign `NULL` to `list->next`. This means that `list->next now points to the memory location`0x0000` which is not available to you. It is used to store some basic information that the OS requires to properly run the program.

```
list->next->val=2;  <----- This is where the problem ends (your program with it)
```

You try to access something at `0x0000` which is a big no-no. So the Operating system detects this, terminates you, and stops you from destroying everything it loves and cares about.